# 2013 error Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

Query 1 is

> ```
> SELECT id,state,submission_id FROM document WHERE submission_id>=0;
> ```

```
+---------+-------+---------------+
| id      | state | submission_id |
+---------+-------+---------------+
| 3000001 |    -1 |         12345 | 
+---------+-------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Obviously, there is only one record with submission_id >=0.

Query 2 is

> ```
> SELECT id,state,submission_id FROM document WHERE submission_id>=0 OR state=0 ORDER BY submission_id LIMIT 5;
> ```

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

The third query is after I simply wait for 10 minutes

> SELECT * from document WHERE state=0 OR submission_id>=0 order by
>   submission_id desc limit 5;

```
+----+-------+---------------+
| id | state | submission_id |
+----+-------+---------------+
|  1 |     1 |            -1 | 
|  2 |     1 |            -1 | 
|  3 |     1 |            -1 | 
|  4 |     1 |            -1 | 
|  5 |     1 |            -1 | 
+----+-------+---------------+
```

What's wrong? The id=3000001 item should be the first, right?

This happens after I indexed the column "submission". Is there anyway to remove this column from being indexed?

For reference "describe document" looks like

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| state         | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| submission_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | 
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: You need to check your MySQL error logs. You shouldn't be losing your connection in a query like that. Maybe you have corruption. Alternatively, what version of MySQL is this? Maybe you've hit a bug.

Comment: And have you checked the server logs for errors, and also run `check table` on the relevant table?

Comment: You're probably right. The error log indicates that there was a crash. It asked me either to decrease the variables in the equation of key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_connections = 225787 K
or solve the stack trace. Actually the index was finished in about 24 hours yesterday but at the 20th hour, I found mysql is doing "copy to temp table". After it "finished" indexing, I run a query like that, and it reported a disk full error to me. I think it was probably because of that. What can I do now?

Comment: Well, your first step is to rectify the disk full error (i.e., free up some disk space). Then adjust `my.cnf` for the amount of RAM you have. After you've got those problems solved, hopefully 'check table' comes up clean, and your queries will work as expected.

Comment: Please run these 2 queries and post their output in your question : 1) `SELECT COUNT(1) state_count,state FROM document GROUP BY state;` and 2) `SELECT COUNT(1) submission_id_count,submission_id FROM document GROUP BY submission_id;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to drop the submission_id index

```
ALTER TABLE document DROP INDEX submission_id;
```

If the name of the index is not submission_id, here is how you can find it:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE document\G
```

You will see the table definition with the indexes defined at the bottom.

You will see the correct name of the index.

Another way to find the name of the submission_id index is:

```
SELECT index_name FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE table_name='document'
AND column_name='submission_id';
```

Comment: DROP INDEX should be followed with an index name, not the name of a column.